# Magento Product image on Hover not working

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, product-images, media-images

I want to add a hover image for my product.

So the first step :

1- i've create a new attribute with code named `hover_image` for all types of the products.

2- in php file `catalog->product->list.phtml` i've add `onmouseover` javascript function to `image` tag like below

`onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'hover_image')->resize(500,659)?>'"`

but it's not working any suggestions ?

Comment: put it in `media/catalog/product/placeholder` and provide what you are adding /storing in that attribute?

Comment: but the `url value` is the `path` of the `hover_image` in `media folder` i want to get the `hover_image` value selected for the product in the admin .

Comment: sry but still not clear

Comment: i've update my question

Comment: just place your image in `media/catalog/product/placeholder`

Comment: i've set the image in their place but i want to get the attribute value

Comment: still unclear will you please explain it with example. your current situation and thing you want to achieve

Comment: i've update my question

Comment: `hover_image` is of type file???

Comment: hover_image is of type `Media image`

Comment: on which page you are trying to get this image?  listing or view?

Comment: in `catalog->product->list.phtml` i want to get this image

Answer (score 1):

here is working code you can try this

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(224); ?>" width="226" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'hover_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(224) ?>';" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(224) ?>';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Load again

```
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
```

Now try with new object

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'hover_image')->resize(500,659)
```

Comment: i've got an empty value

Comment: @mahmoudismail please find updated answer

Comment: sry it's not working

Comment: @mahmoudismail have you refer this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9769386/7089203

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete working code you can use, please remember to upload placeholder

```
 <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
    <?php $hoverImage = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'hover_image')->resize(300,470)->setQuality(100);
    if (strpos($hoverImage, 'place-holder') == false) { ?>
    <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
        src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(300,470)->setQuality(100); ?>"
        alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"
        onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'hover_image')->resize(300,470)->setQuality(100) ?>';"
        onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(300,470)->setQuality(100); ?>';"
    />


    <?php } else { ?>
    <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
    src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(300,470)->setQuality(100); ?>"
    alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"

    />        
    <?php } ?>
</a>
```

You can uplaod place holder via backend System > Configtration > Catlouge > product image placeholder

[image]